# How to show summary of Flask form data in html?

Tags: python, html, flask

I have created a multi-step form and on the final "page", I want it to be a "review order" sort of thing where I summarize all of the users inputs from the previous pages. I'm having trouble actually getting the inputs to show on that final page, though (using my current method). Here is what I have so far and the part I'm struggling with is in html section under `Pipeline Input Review`:

**app.py**:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def pipeline():

    form = InputForm(request.form)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        STACK_NAME = form.stack_name.data
        BUCKET = form.bucket.data
        KEY_PAIR = form.key_pair.data

    return render_template('pipeline-alt.html', 
                            title='Pipeline Input', 
                            form=form)
```

**pipeline-alt.html:**

```
<form method="POST" id="regForm" action="">
  <h1>Pipeline Input</h1>
  <div class="tab">
    <h3>Pipeline Infrastructure:</h3>
    <label>Stack Name</label>
    <input placeholder="(e.g. my-pipeline-run)..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="stack_name"></input>
    <label>Pipeline Deployment S3 Bucket</label>
    <input placeholder="bucket name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="bucket">
    <label>Key Pair</label>
    <select placeholder="key pair..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="key_pair">

  <!-- Current attempt at accessing the input data -->

  <div class="tab">
    <h3>Pipeline Input Review:</h3>
    <label>Stack Name: {{ form.stack_name.data }}</label>
    <label>Pipeline Deployment S3 Bucket: {{ form.bucket.data }}</label>
    <label>Key Pair: {{ form.key_pair.data }}</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Input Form:**

```
class InputForm(FlaskForm):

    bucket_choices = [("", "---")] + [("", bucket["Name"]) for bucket in s3_client.list_buckets()["Buckets"]]
    ref_choices = [("", "---")] + [("", bucket["Name"]) for bucket in s3_client.list_buckets()["Buckets"]]
    key_choices = [("", "---")] + [("", pair["KeyName"]) for pair in ec2_client.describe_key_pairs()["KeyPairs"]]

    stack_name = StringField('STACK NAME', validators=[validators.required()])
    bucket = SelectField('PIPELINE DEPLOYMENT BUCKET', validators=[validators.required()], choices=bucket_choices)
    key_pair = SelectField('KEY PAIR', validators=[validators.required()], choices=key_choices)
```

**UPDATE 2 ATTEMPT:**

**pipeline-alt.html**

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}

<form method="POST" id="regForm" action="{{ url_for('pipeline') }}">
  <h1>Pipeline Input</h1>
  <br>
  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab">
    <h3>Pipeline Infrastructure:</h3>
    <br><br>
    <label>Stack Name</label>
    {{ form.stack_name(placeholder="(e.g. my-pipeline-run)...", oninput="this.className = ''")}}
    <label>Pipeline Deployment S3 Bucket</label>
    {{ form.bucket(placeholder="Deployment bucket name...", oninput="this.className = ''") }}
    <label>Key Pair</label>
    {{ form.key_pair(placeholder="AWS ssh key pair...", oninput="this.className = ''") }}
    <label>Start Point</label>
    {{ form.start_point(placeholder="Start point..", oninput="this.className = ''") }}
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <h3>Review</h3>
        <label>Stack Name: <span id="stack_name_label">{{ STACK_NAME }}</span></label>
        <br>
        <label>Pipeline Deployment S3 Bucket: <span id="bucket_label">{{ BUCKET }}</span></label>
        <br>
        <label>AWS SSH Key Pair: <span id="gpce_ssh_key_pair_label">{{ GPCE_SSH_KEY_PAIR }}</span></label>
        <br>
        <label>Start Point: <span id="start_point_label">{{ START_POINT }}</span></label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>
</form>

<script>
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the crurrent tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}

</script>
<script>

$(function() {
    $('#stack_name').on('change keyup paste', function(){
        $(#'stack_name_label').text($(this).val());
    });
    $('#bucket').change(function(){
        $(#'bucket_label').text($(this).val());
    });
    $('#key_pair').change(function(){
        $(#'key_pair_label').text($(this).val());
    });
    $('#start_point').change(function(){
        $(#'start_point_label').text($(this).val());
    });
});

</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the form correctly and I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but here is how you should be using the form

**In your HTML**

```
<form method="POST" id="regForm" action="{{url_for('pipeline')}}">
  <h1>Pipeline Input</h1>
  <div class="tab">
    <h3>Pipeline Infrastructure:</h3>
    <label>Stack Name</label>
    {{ form.stack_name(placeholder='yourplaceholder', oninput="this.className....") }}

    <label>Pipeline Deployment S3 Bucket</label>
    {{ form.bucket(placeholder='bucket name')}}
    <label>Key Pair</label>
    {{ form.key_pair }}

  <!-- Current attempt at accessing the input data -->

  <div class="tab">
    <h3>Pipeline Input Review:</h3>
    <label>Stack Name: <span id="stack_label">{{ STACK_NAME }}</span></label>
    <label>Pipeline Deployment S3 Bucket: <span id="bucket_label"> {{ BUCKET }}</span></label>
    <label>Key Pair: <span id="key_pair_label">{{ KEY_PAIR }}</span></label>
  </div>
</form>
```

**In your app.py**

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def pipeline():
    form = InputForm(request.form)
    STACK_NAME = ''
    BUCKET = ''
    KEY_PAIR = ''

    if request.method == 'POST':
        STACK_NAME = request.form['stack_name'] # this is how you access the value of the input
        BUCKET = request.form['bucket']
        KEY_PAIR = request.form['key_pair']

    return render_template('pipeline-alt.html', 
                            title='Pipeline Input', 
                            form=form,
                            STACK_NAME=STACK_NAME,
                            BUCKET=BUCKET,
                            KEY_PAIR=KEY_PAIR
)
```

When you want to use a WTForm in your template you can access the inputs by using `{{form.input_name}}`. This will render an HTML `<input>` tag in your form (or `<select>` depending on your form definition). Don't use `{{form.inpute_name.data}}`

In your view, to access the data submitted with the form you use `request.form['input_name']` if the form method is of type `POST` or `request.args.get('input_name')` if the form method is of type `GET`

**UPDATE**

You should make sure that your choices tuple's first element is not the empty string since this is the value that gets passed to your view when you submit the form.

try to change it as follows:

```
class InputForm(FlaskForm):

    bucket_choices = [("", "---")] + [('bucket["Name"]', bucket["Name"]) for bucket in s3_client.list_buckets()["Buckets"]]
    ref_choices = [("", "---")] + [('bucket["Name"]', bucket["Name"]) for bucket in s3_client.list_buckets()["Buckets"]]
    key_choices = [("", "---")] + [('pair["KeyName"]', pair["KeyName"]) for pair in ec2_client.describe_key_pairs()["KeyPairs"]]

    stack_name = StringField('STACK NAME', validators=[validators.required()])
    bucket = SelectField('PIPELINE DEPLOYMENT BUCKET', validators=[validators.required()], choices=bucket_choices)
    key_pair = SelectField('KEY PAIR', validators=[validators.required()], choices=key_choices)
```

**UPDATE #2**

You did not specify in your original question that you want to reflect the change of an input immediately before the form is submitted. This is only possible using javascript.

Add the below javascript code to your HTML. These are event listeners that listen for any change in your form inputs. Every time a change is detected, the appropriate label text will change accordingly. Also checkout the updated HTML code above. I added `<span>` tags inside your labels in order to reflect the changes from the javascript code

```
$(function(){
    $('#stack_name').on('change keyup paste', function(){
        $(#'stack_label').text($(this).val());
    });
    $('#bucket').change(function(){
        $(#'bucket_label').text($(this).val());
    });
    $('#key_pair').change(function(){
        $(#'key_pair_label').text($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I implement your solution, 1) STACK_NAME comes out as empty on the final page, 2) the reason why I wasn't having the inputs be in the form of `{{ form.input-name ....}}` is because I wasn't sure how to deal with inputs that have dynamic options. For instance the `BUCKET` input is actually meant to be dropdown style, and the options come from an AWS API request (performed in **app.py** and passed to the HTML file) to get the user's list of buckets.

Comment: Please see added info to my question about dynamic form inputs. (Sorry, I accidentally edited your response instead of my question, so please ignore that!)

Comment: never mind, I solved problem 2). But I'm still getting problem 1) -- the variables are showing as blank on the "review" page.

Comment: Sure, I've posted it above!

Comment: see my update and let me know if this solves the problem

Comment: I tried the update and still have the same issue. So it's not that the "options" come up blank in the form. It's that, when I go through and fill out the form inputs, on the final page, when I want to print out those inputs, they show up as blank, even though I filled them in. So I guess that means there's an issue with "Review" section in the HTML file in terms of how I'm referencing the inputs (i.e. this part `<label>Stack Name: {{ STACK_NAME }}</label>`). Hopefully it's not the case where I can't print out the input values until I click the "submit" button.

Comment: You cannot expect the values to be updated without hitting the submit button and without using javascript. I added some javascript code in another update of the answer to achieve what you are trying to. In general, an HTML page is only rendered once when it is loaded. To make any changes to it without refreshing it (or submitting a form for that purpose) you have to use javascript

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179199/discussion-between-claudiadast-and-shifloni).